# Purpose of interface variable in C# class implementation

Tags: c#, roslyn, rider

So, beginning to get familiar with the Rider IDE. I defined an interface, then set up a class to implement the interface. When I used the Roslyn fix to implement interface members, it generated something that I had not noticed before, and I am wondering what the purpose of it is.

```
interface IThing
{
    string GetThing();
}
```

Then, when I generate the boilerplate:

```
class ThingClass : IThing
{
    private IThing ThingImplementation;

    public string GetThing()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So, what is the instance of `IThing` `ThingImplementation` for?

Comment: You probably selected the "implement interface by delegating to a field" action.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, now that you mention it I do recall experimenting with that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rider offers two quick fixes for implementing interfaces.

[image: Rider quick fixes]

The first one 'Implement missing members' yields the following (expected) code:

```
class ThingClass : IThing
{
    public string GetThing()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The second one 'Delegate implementation of 'IThing' to new field' yields the code in your original question:

```
class ThingClass : IThing
{
    private IThing thingImplementation;
    public string GetThing()
    {
        return thingImplementation.GetThing();
    }
}
```

The second version is useful when you want to change implementations "on-the-fly". Maybe depending on a constructor parameter, or whatever your use case is.